# Why does not ArrayList override equals() for better performance?

Tags: java, arraylist

`ArrayList` inherits `equals` implementation from its parent class `AbstractList` which is not very effective.

It could first check the size of the two ArrayLists and then return `false` immediately if these sizes are different. Why does not `ArrayList` do that?

Comment: Try reading this thread http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/239139/why-do-arrays-in-java-not-override-equals

Comment: I don't think that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958113/jdk-implementation-of-abstractlistequals-does-not-check-for-list-size-equali) question is a duplicate, voted for reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, a decision to override `ArrayList.equals()` and `ArrayList.indexOf()` was made: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8196340. Benchmarks show a tangible performance gain.

Answer (score 7):

As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958113/jdk-implementation-of-abstractlistequals-does-not-check-for-list-size-equali), this is not done because some implementations has O(n) complexity of their `size` method, so this can be indeed a *degradation*.

I agree that making `equals` consistent in all lists implementations can affect collections that has O(1) size complexity, but maybe Java developers thought that it's much *easier* to insert it when you need than removing it when you don't (you'll have to re-implement the whole method!). For example, you can easily add this optimization with something like:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    // here it is
    if (o instanceof List && this.size() != ((List)o).size())
        return false;

    // call the parent equals
    return super.equals(o);
```

But if it was originally implemented with the size check (in the abstract class), you had to re-implement the whole method and remove the size check:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this)
        return true;
    if (!(o instanceof List))
        return false;

    ListIterator<E> e1 = listIterator();
    ListIterator<?> e2 = ((List<?>) o).listIterator();
    while (e1.hasNext() && e2.hasNext()) {
        E o1 = e1.next();
        Object o2 = e2.next();
        if (!(o1==null ? o2==null : o1.equals(o2)))
            return false;
    }
    return !(e1.hasNext() || e2.hasNext());
}
```

Comment: Ah, what I missed when I was thinking about it - whilst the default implementation of `size()` is `O(1)`, it is not `final`, so you cannot guarantee that it has not been overridden. Obvs.

Comment: Maybe I'm not yet awake, but ... couldn't you just call `return super.equals(o);` instead of manually doing the iteration?